# SQL - String Logic

Tags: sql, arrays, string, logic

I don't know if what I am wanting to achieve is possible so here is my conundrum.

Within a SQL table there are a number of fields that contain yes/no flags in a string so for example.  On the field may be be called 'Stock' and within this one field there is a string of flags which e.g. 'YNYYY' lets say for example that the flags stand for.

- Coke
- Fanta
- Pepsi
- Lilt
- Dr Pepper

in this instance I would want in my return of data to return Coke,Pepsi,Lilt,Dr Pepper ommiting the Fanta.

Now this would be possible using the CASE Statement and this may be the answer that I have to use, however ideally so I don't have to write hundreds of different variables anyone know of a way this could be achieved?

Your help as always appreciated, I've done the normal googling and maybe I simply don't know what to search for as its giving me blanks.

Please point me in the right direction.

Regards

R

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `SELECT` with `WHERE`?

Something like this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Stock`) 
 FROM table_name 
 WHERE `flag` = 'Y'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, so here is the kicker...  It would be easy to create a table or select the data from a table but the challenge that I have here is that the datasource is read only.  So I cannot create tables hence the difficulties with this one.  Your help is most appreciated!

Comment: I did not get you.. What is the problem with executing the query?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve your goal is by writing a table valued function that turns your `Y/N` string into a table of `(Id INT, value BIT)`, you could then join to a look up table based on convention. Here's what something like this would look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_StringToBool(@intput varchar(100))
RETURNS @table TABLE (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
        Value BIT
    )
AS
begin

    declare @temp_input varchar(100) = @intput
    while len(@temp_input) > 0 
    begin
        insert into @table (value)  
        SELECT CASE LEFT(@temp_input, 1) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

        set @temp_input = right(@temp_input, len(@temp_input)-1)
    END

    RETURN

end
```

You would then join your `stock` (and a lookup to product) table with this function, then remove any that are not in stock in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT s.*, v.Value, pl.Name
FROM 
     stock s 
     cross apply 
     ( 
         select b.* from udf_StringToBool(s.Flags) b
     ) v
     join product_lookup pl on pl.Id = v.Id
WHERE v.Value = 1
```

Here's how you would define the lookup table:

```
create table product_lookup 
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Name Varchar(50)
) 

insert into product_lookup (Name) values 
('Coke'),
('Fanta'),
('Pepsi'),
('Lilt'),
('Dr Pepper')
```

Then you could use PIVOT to generate the columns with booleans.

Comment: Hi Buddy, sadly creating a table is not possible with this solution the database is read only so has to be discounted and the datatable of where the stock logic comes from is not available.  As I said this may be just a flight of fantasy and reliant on the case statement.  Help appreciated though!

Comment: Then put all of this into a stored proc.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't consider this either!  I will look at doing so, that makes a perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I chose to use 'substring' and the 'case' statement so that each item appeared in it's own field this way I mitigated the need to write every variable.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(STOCK,1,1) = 'y' THEN 'IN STOCK' ELSE 'OUTOFSTOCK' END AS COKE
```

I don't know why it didnt occur to me to begin with and without your prompting and guidance I would have probably done this the long way round as ever thanks to all!